# VPN Trough Reverse SSH

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVbWT.png)

I have:

- Client behind a nat
- VPS(AWS)
- OpenVPN server installed in a different nat

I want to connect from my client to the OpenVPNServer trough the VPS.

I have been able to create a reverse ssh tunnel from the openvpn server to the VPS and expose some ports (web, ftp, ssh) and access them from my client succesfully.

```sh
ssh -R 9352:localhost:80 user@vps.com
```

This is not working if I try to expose the OpenVPN port and connect from my client, the connection just get reset and there are no logs of any attempted connection in the OpenVPN Server.

What I'm probably missing?

Comment: Easier solution would be just run the VPN server on the VPS, or run another VPN server on the VPS and chain.  The performance of tunneling OpenVPN inside SSH is going to seriously suck.

Comment: If I do it that way, It will allow me to be in the same lan as the first client?